# `thumbnail.so` preventing from ejecting USB

Tags: process, usb

What is what `thumbnail.so` process, what does it belong to and why is it locking usb stick from ejecting?
(the system is debian Buster with KDE)

Comment: It looks like a shared library to and not a process. How do you know it prevents USB ejecting?

Comment: I've got the same problem in Kubuntu. I can't eject my external drives because of thumbnail.so processes. I found the processes by using lsof, and when I kill them I can unmount the external drives.